# call field into other model in odoo | openerp

Tags: python

I want to call following field from **_name = "product.template" model**:

```
    `'barcode': fields.related('product_variant_ids', 'barcode', type='char', string='Barcode', oldname='ean13')
```

above field i wanted to refer in other model named: 
**_name = 'sale.order.line**

something like this:

```
'barcode': fields.char('product.template', 'barcode'),
```

However above line of code throws error:**AssertionError: Char field sale.order.line.barcode with non-integer size 'barcode'**

can anyone guide me to call barcode field of one model into other model?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
'barcode':fields.related('product_id','ean13',type="char",size=13,string="Barcode")
```